# svn-git emits warnings about empty directories for source files

Tags: svn, git

Running `svn-git clone` on my SVN repo and I'm getting lots of warnings like these:

```
W: -empty_dir: trunk/3rdPartyLibInst/PLX/Include/Reg9050.h
W: -empty_dir: trunk/3rdPartyLibInst/PLX/Include/Reg9054.h
W: -empty_dir: trunk/3rdPartyLibInst/PLX/Include/Reg9056.h
```

These are header source files and it's giving me warnings about them being treated as empty dirs? Anybody know what's going on here?

Doesn't only happen to `.h` files, btw. Also to `.lib` files, `.tlb`, and others.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've noticed that before. It's probably just a badly worded error message; doesn't actually hurt anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: worries me. I might need to do some sort of directory hierarchy comparison at the end to make sure files weren't wiped out...